# MoEngage - React Native UIViewController that is already being presented

Tags: ios, react-native, moengage

After following the instruction on the website, I got this error when I try to build on iOS:

```
Thread 1: "Application tried to present modally a view controller <UIViewController: 0x7f90684afee0> that is already being presented by <UIViewController: 0x7f906847c320>."
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7tUUE.png

[phone error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QXKuh.png)

`Info.plist`

```
<key>MoEngage</key>
<dict>
    <key>MoEngage_APP_ID</key>
    <string>...</string>
</dict>
...
```

`AppDelegate.m`

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
...
  // Set Data Center
  [MoEngage setDataCenter:DATA_CENTER_01]; //DATA_CENTER_01, DATA_CENTER_02, OR DATA_CENTER_03
  
  [[MOReactInitializer sharedInstance] intializeSDKWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
  
  return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the issue fixed, for me it's because two lines in the file `AppDelegate` is putting in wrong position. Make sure these:

```
  [MoEngage setDataCenter:DATA_CENTER_01]; //DATA_CENTER_01, DATA_CENTER_02, OR DATA_CENTER_03
  
  [[MOReactInitializer sharedInstance] intializeSDKWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions];
```

are in right position of the `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` function, in my case is to put them right before:

```
RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"finan"
                                            initialProperties:nil];

rootView.backgroundColor = [[UIColor alloc] initWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:1];
```

Answer (score 0):

MoEngageSDK presents the ViewController only incase of RichLanding. The above mentioned error points to the

> react-native-splash-screen

plugin as you are calling `[RNSplashScreen show];` in AppDelegate. So the issue seems to be from `react-native-splash-screen` plugin.

Also, for the other error. You need to make sure

```
[[MOReactInitializer sharedInstance] intializeSDKWithLaunchOptions:launchOptions]
```

is being initialized properly.

Also, you can check with the support team of moengage to resovle this at
https://help.moengage.com/